# Nested Ajax not executing in sequence

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, promise, geonames

I am using geonames api thats get geographical related information. I am trying to get the states name in country using getStateInfo function and then I am trying to get the cities in the state using getCityInfo function. I wanted to get one state and then cities under the state but below code executes the getStateInfo function first and then goes to next function getCityInfo because of this issue I am not able to map correct cities in state. Is there a way I can print one state and then print  all cities in state?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var finalList = ''
            getStateInfo().then(
                function (statedata, status, jqXHR) {
                    var countryName = statedata["geonames"][0].countryName;
                    var stateName = ''
                    var fullStateList = ''
                    var fullCityName;
                    $("#Level1").text(countryName);                    
                    for (i = 0; i < statedata["geonames"].length; i++) {
                        getCityInfo(statedata["geonames"][i].geonameId).then(
                            function (citydata, status, jqXHR) {
                                for (i = 0; i < citydata["geonames"].length; i++) {
                                    cityName = citydata["geonames"][i].toponymName                                
                                    console.log(cityName)
                                }
                            },
                            function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                                var err = eval("(" + jqXHR.responseText + ")");
                                alert("fail");
                                
                            });
                        stateName = "<li>" + statedata["geonames"][i].adminName1 + "</li>"
                        fullStateList += stateName;
                    }                    
                    $("#Level2").append(fullStateList);
                },
                function (jqXHR, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + jqXHR.responseText + ")");
                    alert("fail");
                    console.log(err.Message);
                });
        });

        function getCityInfo(stateGeoId) {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            dfd = $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=" + stateGeoId + "&username=mydev199&hierarchy=geography",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "jsonp",                
            });
            return dfd.promise();
        }

        function getStateInfo() {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            dfd = $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=6252001&username=mydev199&hierarchy=geography",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "jsonp",                
            });
            return dfd.promise();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ApplicationResults" class="resultSet">
        <ul id="myUL">
            <li>
                <span class="caret" id="Level1"></span>
                <ul class="nested" id="Level2"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what final output you want, but here's a general structure for getting all the data, then inserting it into the page while keeping all the data in order:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var finalList = ''
            getStateInfo().then(function (statedata, status, jqXHR) {
                var countryName = statedata["geonames"][0].countryName;
                var stateName = ''
                var fullStateList = ''
                var fullCityName;
                $("#Level1").text(countryName);
                // loop through  all the items and get their data
                // let Promise.all() collecta all the data in order for us, before we process it
                Promise.all(statedata.geonames.map(function(item) {
                    return getCityInfo(item.geonameId).then(function(cityInfo) {
                        return cityInfo.geonames.map(function(location) {
                            return {name: location.toponymName, code: location.adminCode1};
                        });
                    });
                })).then(function(data) {
                    // now insert all the data in the page
                    let spot = $("#myUL");
                    data.forEach(function(collection) {
                        console.log(collection);
                        let root = $("<li>");
                        root.append('<span class="caret" id="Level1">' + collection[0].code + '</span>');
                        let r = $('<ul class="nested" id="Level2"></ul>');
                        collection.forEach(function(region) {
                            r.append('<li>' + region.name + '</li>');
                        });
                        root.append(r);
                        spot.append(root);
                    });
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        });

        function getCityInfo(stateGeoId) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=" + stateGeoId + "&username=mydev199&hierarchy=geography",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "jsonp",                
            });
        }

        function getStateInfo() {
            return $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/childrenJSON?geonameId=6252001&username=mydev199&hierarchy=geography",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "jsonp",                
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ApplicationResults" class="resultSet">
        <ul id="myUL">
            <li>
                <span class="caret" id="Level1"></span>
                <ul class="nested" id="Level2"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you put this into an HTML file and load it into the browser, you can run it directly.  Because there are a lot of nested queries, it takes a long time to run.  You can tweak the generated HTML to your liking.

This code uses `Promise.all()` to run all the queries in parallel and to collect all the results in order.  Then, only when we have all the results in order, does it then iterate them in order and built the HTML.

I also simplified `getStateInfo()` and `getCityInfo()` as there was no reason to be creating a deferred in those functions.  You can just directly return the promise from `$.ajax()`.